# Implications of Having an object_id Column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the implications of having a object_id / object_type on a model (for a polymorphic association) in regards to `Object` itself containing an `object_id` and that overriding it (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-object_id)?

```
class Event
  belongs_to :object, polymorphic: true # object_id/object_type
end
```

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: @spickermann this is code that lives in a product app - it is being 'tried'. The thing I'm worried about is that lots of the side effects might be hidden (i.e. if Ruby uses `object_id` for GC - this could cause memory leaks - that are extremely difficult to track down). Refactoring to fix is challenging - so I'd like to know the impact if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I search for `object_id` through the whole codebase of one of my rails projects (including all gems), I can see over 200 hits. In Rails only, this is [about 50 hits](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=object_id).

I'd expect problems with records comparison, using them as hash keys, putting them to `set`s, perhaps also [duplicating](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#duplicable-questionmark) them with `dup`. In Rails, `record.object_id` is referenced in caching, `has_many_through` associations, AREL, pretty printing the record, minitest expectations, also in pry debugger,

But just from quick-looking trough the code it is very hard to guess if it will cause problems or not and I generally tend to be very defensive about such potential problems - you'll never know for sure if your next usage of the `object` will not break things in a way that is both very hard to debug and perhaps impossible to fix.

As I said above, I'd be very curious if you tried, but myself would rather name it `belongs_to :thing, polymorphic: true` or better yet something even more specific.

Comment: The app is already live and doesn't seem to have any noticeable problems (outside some Ruby memory leaks - which may or may not be related). I agree - and wouldn't use `object_id` again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12632815)

Comment: @TobySpeight you are right, though at least I tried to search for `object_id` through ruby and rails code and described my observations. This wouldn't fit in a comment anyway. I guess there is no definite answer for such question perhaps someone will have a more particular experience to add here.

Comment: Given that the question is "Implications of Having an object_id Column in Rails", I think that this answer does a bang-up job of pointing out the implications.  While not exhaustive, it's pretty reasonably thorough in covering the (somewhat surprising) aspects of Ruby and Rails that will likely have some kind of issue.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill thanks, though I guess the OP expected still something more thorough, as this answer has been placed even before the bounty began.

Answer (score 3):

If you attempt to define `object_id` on a class you'll find that you get the following angry warning from the Ruby interpreter `warning: redefining 'object_id' may cause serious problems` (try it from IRB). That sounds scary - and the incidents may be tied to specific versions of Ruby (and vary based on the version used). I'd recommend fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can belong_to object, while defining the foreign_key to something else, like foreign_key: :object_identifier. That way you dont have to worry about object_id.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best to follow this documentation [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), I think defining another object_id will make you sustain the relation manually in your code and you will lose Active Record features for doing that.